Hide and show div based on incrementing select ID
I am trying to hide and show an input wrapped inside js/html dynamic table. The input shows only when an option is selected. I am trying to retain an array of OTHER option in case a client selects OTHER from different dynamic table rows.
The problem Im facing is that, its only working before adding another table row dynamically
Below is my html code
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>
       <select class="form-control select2" id="selectId_1" name="myvalue[]" required>
        <option value="val 1">.......</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
     </select>
     <input type="text" class="form-control other" id="other_1" name="other[]" class="form-control " placeholder="other category" ></td>
     <td><input autocomplete="off" class="form-control quantity" id="quantity_1" name="quantity[]" type="number"></td>
     <td>...</td>
   </tr>
 </table>

Here is the js code which seems to only work on the first row
        $('[id^=selectId_]').each(function (i) {
    i++;
    $(this).change(function () {
      if( $(this).val()==="Other"){
        $('#other_'+i).show();
        }
      else{
        $('#other_'+i).hide()
      }
    });
});


When you add another table row, your new <select> is not going to inherit the onChange attribute.  Your Javascript probably runs once -- it doesn't affect anything added later.  You need to call .change on your new <select> after you add it.

If the event listener is on a parent element (like, the table) it's not an issue with new rows added. The only thing is that you need to test the target of the change event.
If you use the disabled property on the "other" input, the input is not included in the submit request. At the same time the property can be used for hiding the input.


$('#myTable').change(function(event) {
  let target = event.target;
  let form = target.form;
  if (target.type == 'select-one') {
    form[`other_${target.dataset.id}`].disabled = (target.value == 'Other') ? false : true;
  }
});
input:disabled {
  display: none;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form01">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control select2" id="selectId_1" data-id="1" name="myvalue[]" required>
          <option value="val 1">.......</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="form-control other" id="other_1" name="other[]" class="form-control " placeholder="other category" disabled></td>
      <td><input autocomplete="off" class="form-control quantity" id="quantity_1" name="quantity[]" type="number"></td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control select2" id="selectId_2" data-id="2" name="myvalue[]" required>
          <option value="val 1">.......</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="form-control other" id="other_2" name="other[]" class="form-control " placeholder="other category" disabled></td>
      <td><input autocomplete="off" class="form-control quantity" id="quantity_2" name="quantity[]" type="number"></td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>




Thanks @chrwahl for your clear explanation. Because i want to retain data, i can't use disabled, so i modified my original code based on your explanation. Trick was just to add on change function on the parent element. See the edited code above.

@Leo No problem. Good that you found it useful, but don't modify the code in the question. Later on when people find the question/answer it should be possible to see what the issue was.

ok cool let change it back, thanks for the headsup
